# How to add Decibels?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

I have just started studying Audio Engineering and I have come across a section where I need to add decibel levels together.

I am aware that adding two decibel levels together will always give you the answer of +3dB (e.g, 90dB + 90dB = 93dB)

However, the equation I am using to do this is;

$$\log_{10}\left( 10^{90/10}+10^{90/10}\right).$$

The answer that this gives me is "2,000,000,000"

Is there a step that I am missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Scream loudly. ${}$

Comment: Use the fact that $10\log_{10}(x+x)=10\log_{10}(2x)=10\log_{10}(2)+10\log_{10}(x)$, and $10\log_{10}(2) \approx 3$. By the way, you add the signals not the levels.

Comment: I've edited your post to make the math readable.  Can you please check that I didn't change what you indented to write?  What you originally typed was a little unclear to me (I'm not sure what the "x" was supposed to be doing in there).

Comment: I think what's missing is you didn't apply the $\log_{10}$ function. The $2000000000$ is what's _inside_ the parentheses, not the final answer. (Your formula is also missing multiplication by 10 at the end, as was already pointed out.)

Comment: Maybe the problem really is that you copied the equation wrong.

Comment: No, the formula you wrote does not give you two billion !

Comment: Why would you need to add dB? To some extent, the whole point is to turn multiplication into addition.

Comment: Hint: $10\log_{10}2=3.0103\cdots$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decibels do not add. What we add is the power (assuming no interference). See the wikipedia page to know how decibels are related to powers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel

$$dB=10\lg P.$$

So if power $P=1$, we have $dB=0$. And if $P=10$, we have $dB=10$. A similarly defined quantity in chemistry is $pH$, which is related to the base-$10$ log (i.e., $\lg$) of the $H^+$ concentration. So to add two decibels, just convert them to powers first, add the powers and then convert back. For $90$ dB, the corresponding $P=10^9$. Adding two $10^9$ gives $2\times 10^9$. Then take the log and multiply by $10$ to get $93$ dB. What you're missing is converting the power back to $dB$.

Comment: Thank you.

To my understanding, Decibel always needs a reference value to "give it meaning". So I understand the equation is basically undoing the decibel to work out the power level, and then I need to turn that power level back into a decibel. 

I suppose what I am struggling with is trying to input that into my calculator. Clearly I need to do some more research on Logarithmic scales. Your answer helped understand the problem further though!

Comment: Yes. $0$ dB is defined as the weakest audible voice to the human ear, if I remember correctly. Though the definition is a bit vague, it serves as a reference point. In the $pH$ example, $1\,\mathrm{mol\cdot L}^{-1}$ was the reference point that defined $pH=0$.